# How to access JSON response within URLSession of HTTP Post request?

Tags: json, swift, http-post, jwt

I'm making an http post request within the XCTest framework in Xcode for a simple UI test for my app. Within the request, the response is returned. I can't access that response outside of the URLSession task, and I need to because it contains a JWT that must be decoded and used for another http post request.

I've tried researching how to do this, but it is hard to know the right path as I am a beginner in Swift. I've tried creating a new json object and assigning that response to it outside of the URLSession, but it just says that it can't find that response, it is outside of scope.

```
// make HTTP request
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}
task.resume()
let response = responseJSON as! [String:Any]
```

The expected results are that I now have my response object outside of the http request and I can then decode it. The actual results is the error:

Use of unresolved identifier 'responseJSON'

Comment: You can't access a variable outside of its scope.

Comment: Thanks for the input rmaddy. My question is how to access it.

Comment: you would normally use a completion handler

Comment: Thank you for the input Scriptable. I will start looking into that now.

Comment: You access it where it's declared.

Comment: rmaddy I think there is a way to get that response outside of the call. I thought I would be able to have a variable that declared beforehand, then inside the call assign the response to it, but I am probably doing it wrong.

Comment: You can't do that here because the URLSession completion handler is called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The request your making is asynchronous. So when you run the line...

```
let response = responseJSON as! [String:Any]
```

the network request hasn't finished yet. So you would normally use a completion handler that will be called when the network returns

Here is an example playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func postSomeData(completion: @escaping ([String: Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    // setup request
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            completion(nil, error)
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            completion(responseJSON, nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

postSomeData() { response, error in
    print(response, error)
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}
```

Output:

> Optional(["id": 1, "title": delectus aut autem, "completed": 0, "userId": 1]) nil

I would also suggest that you use `Codable` for parsing and mapping the JSON response. [Here is an intro](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet) to using Codable but there are lots of resources available online on the subject.